# Devise Current User Can't Get Nested Data to Show in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to make an example app to learn about namespace/scopes/modules

Normally I would user current_user helper but I have Client::Addresses nested in behind and would like to grab say the user's city and just display it on their edit page (devise registration/edit screen)

```
 <%= current_user.?? %>
```

Using the line below. I also added inverse_of as my understanding it'll reverse the relationship as well but no avail.

```
<%= @user.addresses.cacity %>
```

I think this is pretty close @user.id works but adding the rest error reads. Looks like I also dealt with strong params just not sure. I'm doing this to practice namespacing:scopes/modules:

```
 undefined method `cacity' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

It would be great to do something like.

```
<%= current_user.addresses.cacity %>
```

Here's some additional information with what I got so far, let me know if additional info is needed.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :client do
    resources :subscriptions
  end
    # Security Devise Setup
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users

    # Main Pages
    root 'website/page#index'

    # Client Sections
    resources :users do
        scope module: "client" do
            root :to => 'dashboard#index'
            resources :addresses
        end
    end

    namespace :admin do
        root :to => 'panel#index'
    end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Gravtastic
    gravtastic

    # Devise Settings
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    # Model Relationships
    has_many :addresses, :inverse_of => :user, class_name: 'Client::Address'

end
```

client/address.rb

```
class Client::Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :addresses
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.addresses
```

is a collection, and you send a (instance) method `cacity` to a collection, which, as errors states, do not respond to it.

`@user.addresses.first.cacity` would work.

You could limit the relation to `has_one`:

```
has_one :address #...
```

Which will allow you to use the following:

```
@user.address.cacity
```

Comment: I chose the first one. But I do see what you mean, since I want only one record I'm calling up the first one which is a great solution. I also tested the second solution it works too, but I'd like to deal with multiple records. Thanks gave you credit.